# Filtering on month value doesn't return objects

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a `newsItem` object in my datebase. I want to filter my `newsItem` objects based on year and month values. First of all, here is my model:

```
class newsItem(models.Model):
    mainTitle = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    publish_start = models.DateTimeField()
```

When i call this object on shell, output is:

```
In[15]: nItem[0].publish_start
Out[15]: datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 10, 57, 50, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The problem is, when i filter my newsItem objects based on month, i can't get this object. But filtering on Year works fine.

```
newsItem.objects.all().filter(publish_start__year=2015)
```

returns the object but

```
newsItem.objects.all().filter(publish_start__month=7)
```

or

```
newsItem.objects.all().filter(publish_start__day=27)
```

doesn't returns the object.

Comment: Are you sure the object is saved?

Comment: Are you using SQLite or Postgres? Could it be a timezone issue? Did you set it up in your settings?

Comment: Try specifying `USE_TZ = False` in your settings.py file

Comment: @François USE_TZ setting is True and TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Istanbul', which is my time zone. I'm using mysql and object is saved for sure.

Comment: @deusExCore OK, so try with `USE_TZ = False` like Rahul said. It should work. The output you've shown show tzinfo=UTC so I think there is an issue with your settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#month), if you use USE_TZ = True, the datetime objects will be 
converted to the current time zone. Filtering on timezone aware objects requires [time zone definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#database-time-zone-definitions) in your database.